# populating a deep key/value in javascript object with dynamic non-hard-coded path

Tags: javascript

I have

```
let mydata = { 
  section_a: { 
     color: "red", 
     shape: "cube"
  },
  section_b: {
     length: 34
  }
}
```

Now I want to write a function that'll insert a new `key/value` at a path that is dynamic and can change from call to call.

```
let path = "section_b.go.real.deep";
let newKey = "age";
let newVal = 50;
```

so that mydata becomes:

```
 { 
      section_a: { 
         color: "red", 
         shape: "cube"
      },
      section_b: {
         length: 34,
          go: {
             real: {
                deep: {
                   age: 50
                }
             }
          }
      }
    }
```

Is there any technique to allow something like that? creation of a deep element, along with any potential dynamic hierarchy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: Note: The above link discusses mostly accessing the properties, but modifying them to set is either very simple, or a related counterpart already exists (e.g. discussed is lodash's `_.get`, but you just want lodash's `_.set`). Also note, that there are links in that topic, to even more similar topics, that discuss this in a lot of detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```js
let mydata = { 
  section_a: { 
     color: "red", 
     shape: "cube"
  },
  section_b: {
     length: 34
  }
};

let path = "section_b.go.real.deep";
let newKey = "age";
let newVal = 50;

path.split(".").reduce((obj,key) => obj[key] || (obj[key] = {}), mydata)[newKey] = newVal;

console.log(mydata);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the most elegant solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```js
let mydata = { 
  section_a: { 
     color: "red", 
     shape: "cube"
  },
  section_b: {
     length: 34
  }
};

let path = "section_b.go.real.deep";
let newKey = "age";
let newVal = 50;

var items = path.split(".");

var item = mydata;

for (var prop of items) {
  if (!item[prop]) {
    item[prop] = {};
  }
  
  item = item[prop];
};

item[newKey] = newVal;

console.log(mydata);
```

Comment: strange, it works here, but this code copied elsewhere doesn't work. https://repl.it/repls/ScarceJampackedMacroinstruction   any idea why?

Comment: @JasonGenX it works, just the `console.log` make it shorter in output, note the `real: [Object]`